# composer install failed with return code 1

Tags: php, json, composer-php

I'm getting the following error message when I try to run composer install:

> composer install failed with return code 1  composer could not find a
>   composer.json file in /

But there IS a composer.json file in the public_html folder.

When I talked to the host server support they tried it and got a different error message that I missed a ',' in the code which I've since fixed, so when they did it it found the composer.json file

The host server support refused to help me any more as they said it was a developer issue and outside the scope of their support. Grrr!

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the answer is contained in your question.

The error message you're getting suggests that composer is looking for composer.json at the root of your system (/), but you're saying that your composer.json is located in /public_html.

So my guess would be either you're running composer from the wrong directory, or composer is set up to look for a composer.json file in the wrong place.

Hope this helps,

Comment: I tried moving it to the root before and also tried moving it to the .composer folder but got the same error.

Comment: do you know where you're running compose from ?